# Get biggest Hash in an Array of Hashes

Tags: ruby, sorting

What I have: An array of hashes with different sizes.

```
hashes = [{:a => 0}, {:a => 0, :b => 1}, {:b => 1}]
```

What I need: I just need the biggest item.

```
{:a => 0, :b => 1}
```

Is this the right approach or is this inefficient?

```
hashes.sort_by { |h| h.length }.last
```

Or any other ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution works fine, but you can also use `max_by`, it seems more efficient:

```
hashes.max_by(&:length)
#=> {:a=>0, :b=>1}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! Just realized, I need something slightly different. Will accept and open another question for that, because I would have to change the title etc and your answer would be void.